# Arrange $10$ males and $10$ females in two lines, where each line has $5$ males and $5$ females?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

How many arrangements are there if we want to arrange $10$ males and $10$ females in two lines of equal length, where each line has $5$ males and $5$ females?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! It is a general rule here that you show any attempts you made on the problem so where can show you **where** you went wrong or specifically how we can get you to your solution.

Comment: $\binom{10}{5}^2$, and this is not statistics.

Comment: Am taking biostatistics and that is a question that came in the exam

Comment: 10p5.10p5+5p5.5p5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose $5$ males, that is $\binom{10}{5}$, then choose $5$ females, that is also $\binom{10}{5}$. Now, there are left another $5$ males and $5$ females to the other line. Next, each such line has $10!$ possible arrangements of the people in it, thus in total you have
$$
\binom{10}{5}\binom{10}{5}10!10!
$$